# How to set aws amplify data in localStorage ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

I'm making ReactJS App powered by AWS Amplify framework.

I wanted to make custom signUp component. Everything works fine except that my localStorage is empty.

While I was using "withAuthenticator" method of authentication localStorage was full of data which was important for application to work, now its empty.

My question is: How to force aws amplify authentication to put authentication data into localstorage like it is doing in "withAuthenticator" method.

I include code of my signUp function.

```
Auth.signUp({
    username,
    password,
    attributes: {
        email,          
        phone_number 
    },
    validationData: []  
    })
    .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the `localStorage` to interact with it. It works as an essential key/value store, where the data stored never expires.

To write to it you use the `localStorage.setItem()` method, providing the key and the value as its arguments.

You can later read the contents of a key by using the `localStorage.getItem()` method.

Please check the entire interface documentation here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Answer (score 2):

You can also use Cache from aws-amplify https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/cache

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use the built-in cookie storage if you don't want to manage local storage and let the amplify auth library handle setting and fetching values, from the [create/re-use existing authentication resource](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/start/q/platform/js/#re-use-existing-authentication-resource) docs.
E.g. create Auth instance with cookie storage settings:

```js
Amplify.configure({
  Auth: {
    region: '',
    userPoolId: '',
    userPoolWebClientId: '',
    mandatorySignIn: false,
    cookieStorage: {
      domain: '127.0.0.1',
      path: '/',
      expires: 365,
      sameSite: 'strict',
      secure: true,
    }
  }
});
```

Then in the right place in your app, calling

```js
user = await Auth.currentUserPoolUser()
```

should fetch form cookie storage.  This could be used for example, before component render to check if the user already has a valid session and avoid re-authenticating on page reload.